# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RuntimeContext.getMetricGroup()'

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Flink. I am writing a Flink application (in Java) which consumes data from Kafka topic. I am executing this on my local machine (Apache Kafka 2.13-3.2.0 and Apache Flink 1.14.4). I create the .jar file using Maven and Eclipse. While executing the program, I am getting this error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 4b7ec93f95d0527fcfd9a611be8c1d35)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.getJobExecutionResult(StreamContextEnvironment.java:123)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:80)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1916)
    at kafkademo.kafkademo.KafkaDemo.main(KafkaDemo.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:812)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:246)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1054)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1132)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1132)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 4b7ec93f95d0527fcfd9a611be8c1d35)
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:125)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:403)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$pollResourceAsync$26(RestClusterClient.java:698)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:403)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:610)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1085)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:123)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:138)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:252)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:242)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:233)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:684)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:444)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:316)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:314)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:217)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:163)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RuntimeContext.getMetricGroup()'
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:323)
```

Below are the dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>kafkademo.kafkademo</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafkademo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>


  <name>kafkademo</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <url>https://flink.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <maven-assembly-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <flink.version>1.14.4</flink.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>statefun-flink-distribution</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.4</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-clients_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.4</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
  
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org.apache.flink:force-shading</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>log4j:*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>kafkademo.kafkademo.KafkaDemo</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[3.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>shade</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore/>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore/>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    
  </build>
</project>
```

I checked similar threads here, but none of them is useful. Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full stack trace.

Comment: Also include the full pom. Dependencies only define compile time values. You need to create an uber jar to get classes available at runtime

Comment: I have added the full pom.xml which I am using to create the executable jar.

Comment: Hi @tgdavies,can you please help.

Comment: I'd say it is a version mismatch between your flink dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Statefun 2.2.2 needs to be used with Flink 1.11.3.

Comment: Hello David. Which Flink version would be more suitable for Statefun 3.2.0? I am getting the same metricgroup-related error as the topicstarter

Comment: The Stateful Functions 3.2.0 runtime uses Flink 1.14.3 underneath. See https://flink.apache.org/news/2022/01/31/release-statefun-3.2.0.html

Answer (score 0):

I faced that error, in my case even when flink core dependency version are in "provided" scope, there are some other dependencies like connectors that are not "provided" but in default scope, so those must match in version with runtime

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).